# ошибка list index out of range в таблице

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
a=1
p_array=[[randint(1,10) for m in range(4) for n in range (4)]]
for m in range(4):
    for n in range(4):
        k=p_array[m][n]*a*2
        print(k)
```

код должен выводить таблицу из 4-х столбцов и 4-х рядов со случайных чисел, и выводить на екран умноженные на 2 елементы таблицы

Answer (score 6):

`]` не там поставили. `[ [... for j in range()] for i in range() ]`

```
from random import randint
a=1
p_array=[[randint(1,10) for m in range(4)] for n in range (4)]
for m in range(4):
    for n in range(4):
        k=p_array[m][n]*a*2
        print(k)
```